# QGIS 3.4 Rule Based Symbology - Exact Matches Integers in String e.g. 2,12 + 1,2,3,12

Tags: qgis, vector

I have a shapefile containing a String Type Field called 'Class'. This field contains one or more integers separated by commas.

I want to create Rule-Based symbology matching *only* 2, 12, 1 respectively.

I've tried the following rules with no luck, for the string '1,2,12' each rule matches both 2 + 12 e.g.

Rule 1 - `'Class' LIKE %2%`

Rule 2 - `regexp_match('Class','2')`

[image: Rule-Based Symbology Matching both 2 + 12]

I was thinking adding * before and after each integer when the field is being populated but that would make the field very long. Was hoping there would be a fix for this problem.

Comment: something like regexp_match("Class", '\\b2\\b') - might work. I'm not sure if QGIS supports word boundaries (\b)

Comment: I'm sure **no**t to understand but ... how many classes do u want ? do u mean 3 ? _how do u want to treat the cases where more than one integer are in your string_ ? the rules u showed (rule1 and rule2) won't discriminate 2 and 12 that's awaited ... u want something generic or just working for the dataset you're showing ?

Comment: how about `regexp_match('Class',',2') OR regexp_match('Class','2,')`

Answer (score 2):

How about something like:

```
array_contains(string_to_array("Class", ','), '2')
```

This splits the string in the field "Class" into an array and returns true if the array contains the given value ('2'). This will give you all the features that contain the class/integer 2 (and leave out 12).